# returning drive interface type and drive letter using vbs

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to get the drive interface type and drive letter using a WMI call but the drive letter is always returned as the last assigned drive  on the machine

Can anyone help?

```
'On Error Resume Next
 Option Explicit

 Dim strComputer, objWMIService, colIDiskDrive, objDiskDrive, colLogicalDisk, objLogicalDisk, strDriveLetter, strPNPDeviceID, strDiskLetter, strInterfaceType

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colIDiskDrive = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive",,48)

For Each objDiskDrive in colIDiskDrive
strPNPDeviceID = objDiskDrive.PNPDeviceID
strInterfaceType = objDiskDrive.InterfaceType
Set colLogicalDisk = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk") 

For Each objLogicalDisk in colLogicalDisk
        strDiskLetter = objLogicalDisk.Name
Next

Wscript.Echo strInterfaceType & " " & strDiskLetter
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it rigth, I move the Echo inside second/nested For/Next loop:

```
Option Explicit

Dim strComputer, objWMIService, colIDiskDrive, objDiskDrive, colLogicalDisk, objLogicalDisk, strDriveLetter, strPNPDeviceID, strDiskLetter, strInterfaceType

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colIDiskDrive = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive",,48)

For Each objDiskDrive in colIDiskDrive
    strPNPDeviceID = objDiskDrive.PNPDeviceID
    strInterfaceType = objDiskDrive.InterfaceType
    Set colLogicalDisk = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk") 

    For Each objLogicalDisk in colLogicalDisk
        strDiskLetter = objLogicalDisk.Name
        Wscript.Echo strInterfaceType & " " & strDiskLetter
    Next
Next
```